# Magento 2.4.3 Bundle Product getting issue on frontend Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Flat::getLinkField()

Tags: magento2.4, magento2.4.3, bundle-product

We have upgraded magento to 2.4.3-p1 and added new bundle product.
On frontend when we access bundle product it show error
Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Flat::getLinkField()

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
                "Magento_Catalog/js/product/view/provider": {
                    "data": Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Flat::getLinkField() in /chroot/home/3343sfdsadf/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php:1066
```

it seems like magento added some new files and plugin for bundle product in magento 2.4.3-p1.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\SingleChoiceProvider" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Product\SingleChoiceProvider" />
```

Vendor\Module\Model\Product\SingleChoiceProvider.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type as BundleType;

class SingleChoiceProvider extends \Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\SingleChoiceProvider
{

    public function isSingleChoiceAvailable(Product $product) : bool
    {
        $result = false;
        if ($product->getTypeId() === BundleType::TYPE_BUNDLE) {
            $typeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
            $typeInstance->setStoreFilter($product->getStoreId(), $product);

            if ($typeInstance->hasRequiredOptions($product)) {
                $options = $typeInstance->getOptions($product);
                $isNoCustomizations = true;
                foreach ($options as $option) {
                    $optionId = $option->getId();
                    $required = $option->getRequired();
                    if ($isNoCustomizations && (int) $required === 1) {
                        $selectionsCollection = $typeInstance->getSelectionsCollection(
                            [$optionId],
                            $product
                        );
                        $selections = []; //$selectionsCollection->exportToArray();
                        if (count($selections) > 1) {
                            foreach ($selections as $selection) {
                                if ($isNoCustomizations) {
                                    $isNoCustomizations = (int)$selection['is_default'] === 1
                                        && (int)$selection['selection_can_change_qty'] === 0;
                                } else {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $isNoCustomizations = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                $result = $isNoCustomizations;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Akashmalik did that fix it? We're experiencing similar issues after all bundle products since migrating from 1.9.3 to 2.4.3

Comment: yes rewrite file 

Vendor\Module\Model\Product\SingleChoiceProvider.php

and modify below line

$selections = []; //$selectionsCollection->exportToArray();

Answer (score 2):

Since 2.3 Magento recommends to disable Flat catalog, this would fix that problem

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/catalog-flat.html

> Use of a flat catalog is no longer recommended as a best practice.
> Continued use of this feature is known to cause performance
> degradation and other indexing issues. A detailed description and
> solution is available in the Help Center.
>
> Affected versions include:
>
> - Adobe Commerce on cloud infrastructure, 2.3.x and above
> - Adobe Commerce (On-Premise), 2.3.x and above
> - Magento Open Source, 2.3.x and above
>
> On any release version, some extensions only work with flat tables,
> thus creating a risk if you disable flat tables. If you know that you
> have some extensions that use Flat Catalog indexers, you need to be
> aware of this risk when setting those values to No.

Comment: There's also an open and confirmed bug report for this exact issue here:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33935

Answer (score 0):

Disable the Use Flat Catalog Product from admin.

Path to disable is `Admin->Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Storefront->Use Flat Catalog Product`